# Sort a Range Query Using Zend Lucene

Tags: zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

According to the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html), Zend Lucene is supposed to sort lexicographically. I am finding this is not the case. If I have a query 'avg:[050 TO 300]', yes it will return all values in that range, but it will sort them according to the document id, not the value.

I have found that the find() function can accept additional parameters, allowing me to sort by a specific column (eg `$hits = $index->find($query, 'avg', SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC);`). However, I am creating $query dynamically and do not want to sort every search by 'avg'.

How do I force Lucene to sort the results automatically, lexicographically, when I do a range search? And if that's not possible, how do I dynamically add a sort field to the find function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you sort `$hits` by yourself after getting the result from `$index->find(...)`? Ok this looks like a workaround and will be time-consuming for very large resultsets, but I guess that this is the easiest way in most cases.

Comment: As I'm only sorting for a select number of queries, I set a flag whenever I do THOSE queries and when it comes to finding I do an if/else to find with/without sort. (eg: `if($flag){$hits = $index->find($query, 'avg', SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC);}else{$hits = $index->find($query);}`)